# Duplicate rows when selecting from normalized database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been working on a normalized database, however, I seem to be facing some errors, like duplicate rows.

This is the query I used

```
SELECT N.Product_Name, C.Category , S.sub_categories,SSC.Sub_Sub_Categories
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT Product_Code, Name_Code FROM Product_Table ) P 
JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT Name_Code, Product_Name FROM Product_Name_Table ) N on P.Name_Code = N.Name_Code 
JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT Product_Code, Category FROM category_table ) C on P.Product_Code = C.Product_Code
join ( SELECT DISTINCT Product_Code,sub_categories From sub_categories ) S on P.Product_Code =  S.Product_Code
join ( SELECT DISTINCT Sub_Sub_Categories,Product_Code From sub_sub_categories ) SSC on P.Product_Code =  SSC.Product_Code
```

This is the table output. As you can see, `lindt 90% chocalate`, have chocolates and dark as sub cat and sub_sub_cat , but it appears as individual rows.

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+
| Product_Name                  Category           sub_cat     sub_sub_cat |                                            |               
| Chocolate Bar-90%(Dark) Food Cupboard     Chocolates      Blocks    |                         |                                  |
| Chocolate Bar-70%(Dark) Food Cupboard     Chocolates      Blocks    |                         |                                  |
| Chocolate Bar-70%(Dark) Food Cupboard     Dark            Blocks    |                         |                                  |
| Chocolate Bar-90%(Dark) Food Cupboard     Chocolates     Chocolates |                         |                                  |
| Chocolate Bar-70%(Dark) Food Cupboard     Chocolates     Chocolates |                         |                                  |
| Chocolate Bar-70%(Dark) Food Cupboard     Dark           Dark       |                         |                                  |
|                                                                           |                         |                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

My desired output

```
Product_Name              Category            sub_cat     sub_sub_cat |     |
Chocolate Bar-90%(Dark) Food Cupboard     Chocolates,dark  Blocks,Chocolates    
Chocolate Bar-70%(Dark) Food Cupboard     Chocolates,dark  Blocks,Chocolates
```

Any tips, suggestions or alternative solution to this problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `string_agg()` if you are using SQL Server.

```
select
  Product_Name,
  category,
  string_agg(sub_cat, ',') within group (order by category) as sub_cat,
  string_agg(sub_sub_cat, ',')  within group (order by category) as sub_sub_cat
from myTable
group by
  Product_Name,
  category
```

Comment: @Joel2342 . . . Does this really return what you want?  Based on the results in the question, I would expect the strings to have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `DISTINCT` on the first `select`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT N.Product_Name, C.Category , S.sub_categories,SSC.Sub_Sub_Categories
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT Product_Code, Name_Code FROM Product_Table ) P 
JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT Name_Code, Product_Name FROM Product_Name_Table ) N on P.Name_Code = N.Name_Code 
JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT Product_Code, Category FROM category_table ) C on P.Product_Code = C.Product_Code
join ( SELECT DISTINCT Product_Code,sub_categories From sub_categories ) S on P.Product_Code =  S.Product_Code
join ( SELECT DISTINCT Sub_Sub_Categories,Product_Code From sub_sub_categories ) SSC on P.Product_Code =  SSC.Product_Code
```